# AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'dtype'

Tags: python, numpy, object, int, dtype

I am trying to run a script to obtain data for a number of stocks. Part of the data I am trying to obtain is a liquidity measure (called Amihud liquidity measure). I automated the script but when running the automated script, I get an error after roughly 15-20 succesful returns.
How can I fix this issue?

```
File "script.py", line 23, in <module>
return_data = function.get_data(row[1], row[0])
File "C:\Users\leon_\function.py", line 39, in get_data
print(np.nanmean(illiq))
File "D:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\nanfunctions.py", line 916, in nanmean
avg = _divide_by_count(tot, cnt, out=out)
File "D:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\nanfunctions.py", line 190, in _divide_by_count
return a.dtype.type(a / b)
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'dtype'
```

The part of the code that handles the illiquidity measure:

```
  # Amihuds Liquidity measure
    liquidity_pricing_date = date_1 + datetime.timedelta(days=-20)
    liquidity_pricing_date2 = date_1 + datetime.timedelta(days=-120)
    stock_data = quandl.get(stock_ticker, start_date=liquidity_pricing_date2, end_date=liquidity_pricing_date)
    p = np.array(stock_data['Adj. Close'])
    returns = np.array(stock_data['Adj. Close'].pct_change())
    dollar_volume = np.array(stock_data['Volume'] * p)
    illiq = (np.divide(returns, dollar_volume))
    print(np.nanmean(illiq))
    illiquidity_measure = np.nanmean(illiq, dtype=float) * (10 ** 6)  # multiply by 10^6 for expositional purposes
    return [stock_vola, stock_price_average, illiquidity_measure]
```

Anyone has any idea on how to solve this?

EDIT: This is the script file

```
# Open File Dialog

root = tk.Tk()
root.withdraw()

file_path = filedialog.askopenfilename()

# Load Spreadsheet data
f = open(file_path)

csv_f = csv.reader(f)
next(csv_f)

result_data = []

# Iterate
for row in csv_f:
    return_data = function.get_data(row[1], row[0])
    if len(return_data) != 0:
        # print(return_data)
        result_data_loc = [row[1], row[0]]
        result_data_loc.extend(return_data)
        result_data.append(result_data_loc)

if result_data is not None:
    with open('resuls.csv', mode='w', newline='') as result_file:
        csv_writer = csv.writer(result_file, delimiter=',', quotechar='"', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
        for result in result_data:
            # print(result)
            csv_writer.writerow(result)
else:
    print("No results found!")
```

Comment: Can you add the line with the error please?

Comment: @CeliusStingher added!

Comment: @Leon  `numpy`? This error is usually found in keras.

Answer (score 0):

***[I'd place this as comment but given the length I can not]*** I don't feel like there's enough information for me to help you solve the issue, in your place, I would add this to make sure I understand why is the code failing and at the same time continue the process to finish it. This way you can then work on the files that failed and correct your script while still getting results.

```
root = tk.Tk()
root.withdraw()

file_path = filedialog.askopenfilename()

# Load Spreadsheet data
f = open(file_path)

csv_f = csv.reader(f)
next(csv_f)

result_data = []

# Iterate
for row in csv_f:
    try:
       return_data = function.get_data(row[1], row[0])
       if len(return_data) != 0:
          # print(return_data)
          result_data_loc = [row[1], row[0]]
          result_data_loc.extend(return_data)
          result_data.append(result_data_loc)
    except AttributeError:
          print(row[0])
          print('\n\n')
          print(row[1])
          continue

if result_data is not None:
    with open('resuls.csv', mode='w', newline='') as result_file:
        csv_writer = csv.writer(result_file, delimiter=',', quotechar='"', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
        for result in result_data:
            # print(result)
            csv_writer.writerow(result)
else:
    print("No results found!")
```

Comment: What additional information would you like? I can just add the whole script.

Comment: It's not the script the proble, but the output of the csv that is making the script fail. I don't see anything wrong with the script (and that's why it runs fine for the first few iterations) probably the csv contains some mishaped data or something along the lines that is what makes the script fails.

Comment: Your 'fix' helps a lot, it seems that when I run the script now, I get the error only one time. After that 1 error all the other rows iterate perfectly fine...

Comment: Yes, but keep in mind you are ***skipping*** the files that would produce the error, that's why it works. I added the print so when you execute it from command line, you can visualize the row outputs that would produce the error, and skip them. So you can see the rows and understand the cause behind the AttributeError.

Answer (score 0):

So according to the traceback (thankfully we didn't have to ask for that), the error occurs in:

```
np.nanmean(illiq)
```

where it's trying to adjust the return value to match the `dtype` of an input, probably `illiq`.  At this point in `nanmean` (looking at its code) it has summed the input (after removing `nan`), `tot`, and counted elements `cnt`.  It's written assuming `illiq` is a numeric `numpy` array (preferably `float` dtype since it has to deal with float `np.nan`).

So it works most of the time, but in some cases fails.  What is different about `illiq` in those cases?

```
p = np.array(stock_data['Adj. Close'])
returns = np.array(stock_data['Adj. Close'].pct_change())
dollar_volume = np.array(stock_data['Volume'] * p)
illiq = (np.divide(returns, dollar_volume))
```

Looks like `stock_data` is a `dataframe`, and the inputs are arrays derived from individual `series`.  I believe `stock_data[name].to_num()` is the preferred way of getting an array from a Series, though `np.array(...)` may work most of the time.  `stock_data[name].values` was also used.

I'd suggest applying some tests to `illiq` before this call.  Check `shape` and `dtype` at least. Try to identify what's different in the problem case.

Here's a simple case that produces this error:

```
In [117]: np.nanmean(np.array([0,3],object))                                                                 
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-117-26ab42d92ec9> in <module>
----> 1 np.nanmean(np.array([0,3],object))

<__array_function__ internals> in nanmean(*args, **kwargs)

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/numpy/lib/nanfunctions.py in nanmean(a, axis, dtype, out, keepdims)
    949     cnt = np.sum(~mask, axis=axis, dtype=np.intp, keepdims=keepdims)
    950     tot = np.sum(arr, axis=axis, dtype=dtype, out=out, keepdims=keepdims)
--> 951     avg = _divide_by_count(tot, cnt, out=out)
    952 
    953     isbad = (cnt == 0)

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/numpy/lib/nanfunctions.py in _divide_by_count(a, b, out)
    216         else:
    217             if out is None:
--> 218                 return a.dtype.type(a / b)
    219             else:
    220                 # This is questionable, but currently a numpy scalar can

AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'dtype'
```

`pandas` often creates object dtype Series when one or more values is not a valid number.  That can include strings and `None` values.

Answer (score 0):

The simple answer is that your data is not a numpy datatype. This is likely because the column isn't fully numeric (i.e. contains None or something).

The short solution:

```
print(np.nanmean(pd.to_numeric(illiq)))
```

The quickest way to solve this is to simply coerce the data to a numeric type that numpy likes. This can be done via pandas' `to_numeric` method.

Comment: To anyone venturing across this post: this was downvoted during a revenge downvote-spree from another user. Don't let that discourage you from trying this. it worked for me!